# In VsCode, I want to debug bundled react app by create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

In vscode, I want to debug bundled react app by create-react-app.

Build react app, building files are deployed in apache.

Below execute.

```
npx create-react app test-debug
cd test-debug
npm run build
mv ./build/* /var/www/html/
```

Access `http://localhost/`, I can browse react app.

In vscode, my `launch.json`.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        },
    ]
}
```

When press `F5`, starting debug and chrome.

In App.js, breakpoint not working.